# Unable to connect to iDrac8 over SSH

Tags: dell-poweredge, putty, drac

We are running Dell PowerEdge M630 servers. I have a few updates I need to make on the iDracs but I am unable to make a connection to ssh server. The server is running Integrated Dell Remote Access Controller 8.  When I connect with Putty from a Windows box, I am able to authenticate, but then the terminal hangs with no input and I am never presented with a terminal. SSH is enabled on the iDrac controller. I can establish a connection on port 22 without any issue and I can confirm this when running a telnet ip_address 22, I see a response of "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.0".

This stems to another issue. I would happily manage this from the web admin, but I am having trouble with that as well. I uploaded a new customer certificate, the server validated that the certificate was fine. I rebooted the iDrac, but now when you load the console over HTTPS:/ip_address the following error occurs:

SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_KEY_USAGE

It looks like the key didn't have all the options, but the iDrac accepted it anyway and I can no longer get into the web client. There is no way to bypass this in error in Firefox, Chrome or IE like other certificate errors. Because of this, RACADM commands are not working either.

My attempt is to fix this over SSH, but that is not working per the question in the thread.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to Putty. I was able to SSH to another box with Putty and then use SSH from that host to SSH to the iDrac. When I connected, I was able to get to the admin console and issue racadm commands. I then reverted back to the original certificates, reboot and get the web console access again. I'm not sure why Putty is not allowing the connections, but openSSH on redhat does.